# nested shiny app doesn't work properly

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build a big shiny application, made by several miniapplications.

The idea was to build an application with a navbarPage (A) on the top, constituted by tabPanel(s) and navbarMenu(s), and for some of these voices the possibility to have a "lateral menu" (B) (sidebarPanel or similar) on the left with other voices.

Finally, for each of these voice, the possibility to have just an application structured with a left panel (C) positioned next to the "left menu" (B), and the outputmenu (D) on the right.

Here I report a cropped screenshot to give a visual idea:

[image]

As you can see, the panel C and the outputmenu D are positioned in a separated "scrollable" frame. This problem is visible invoking the shinyApp function when the "1" voice is selected from the "left panel" B.

Here I report a simplified code divided in files:

```
##### Main app code:
MainUI <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(title = "title",
                      ## other voices
                      navbarMenu("voice 5",
                                 tabPanel("menu 1",
                                          uiOutput("menu51")
                                 ),
                                 tabPanel("...")
                      )
  )
)

MainServer <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$menu51 <- renderUI({
    menu51UI
  })

}

##### menu51 code:
menu51UI <- fluidPage(
    navlistPanel(
      "menu 5>1",
      tabPanel("1",
               shinyApp(exampleUI, exampleServer)
               ),
      tabPanel("2"),
      tabPanel("3"),
      widths=c(2,10)
    )
)

BedUtilitiesServer <- function(input, output, session) {
##
}

##### example app code:
exampleUI <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Sort"),
  fluidRow(
    column(2, 
      wellPanel(
        checkboxInput(inputId = 'directory_flag', label = 'Directory path?', value = FALSE),
        fileInput(inputId = "infiles", label = "Choose file(s)", multiple = TRUE),
        checkboxInput(inputId = 'descending_flag', label = 'Descending', value = FALSE),
        checkboxInput(inputId = 'merge_flag', label = 'Merge', value = FALSE),
        actionButton(inputId = "sortbed_button", label="sort file(s)", width = "100%", icon = icon(name="sort")),
        tags$hr(),
        tags$p("Loaded file(s):"),
        verbatimTextOutput("file_loaded")
      )
    ),
    column(8,
           uiOutput("data_tables")
    )
  )
)

exampleServer <- function(input, output, session) {
 ## some computation functions
}
```

In order to avoid this problem, I decided to replace the call to shinyApp(exampleUI, exampleServer) with an uiOutput("example_ui").
The code becames:

```
##### Main app code:
MainUI <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(title = "title",
                      ## other voices
                      navbarMenu("voice 5",
                                 tabPanel("menu 1",
                                          uiOutput("menu51")
                                 ),
                                 tabPanel("...")
                      )
  )
)

MainServer <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$menu51 <- renderUI({
    menu51UI
  })

}

##### menu51 code:
menu51UI <- fluidPage(
    navlistPanel(
      "menu 5>1",
      tabPanel("1",
               ########
               uiOutput("example_ui")
               ),
      tabPanel("2"),
      tabPanel("3"),
      widths=c(2,10)
    )
)

BedUtilitiesServer <- function(input, output, session) {
output$example_ui <- renderUI({
    #######
    exampleUI 
  })
}

##### example app code:
exampleUI <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Sort"),
  fluidRow(
    column(2, 
      wellPanel(
        checkboxInput(inputId = 'directory_flag', label = 'Directory path?', value = FALSE),
        fileInput(inputId = "infiles", label = "Choose file(s)", multiple = TRUE),
        checkboxInput(inputId = 'descending_flag', label = 'Descending', value = FALSE),
        checkboxInput(inputId = 'merge_flag', label = 'Merge', value = FALSE),
        actionButton(inputId = "sortbed_button", label="sort file(s)", width = "100%", icon = icon(name="sort")),
        tags$hr(),
        tags$p("Loaded file(s):"),
        verbatimTextOutput("file_loaded")
      )
    ),
    column(8,
           uiOutput("data_tables")
    )
  )
)

exampleServer <- function(input, output, session) {
 ## some computation functions
}
```

It seems to work, except for the exampleUI that never appears!!!!

How is that possible? Can someone helps me? Any ideas? Any errors?

Comment: What is the reason that you have specified many what I assume are shiny server functions? ( `function(input, output, session) {` ) if you want to make an shiny app comprised of many small shiny applications you could use iframes to display the included shiny applications.

Comment: the reason is simply due to give modularity to the code... If you want to change the code of a "miniapp", you have just to change that "miniapp" code, leaving the code of other apps as it is!
About the iframes, I'd like to use them, but why to use them when you can use shiny R code?
Anyway, can you give me an example? Thank you! ^^

Comment: I see, interesting use of `shinyApp`. i don't have any experience using it in this way so I have to look into this.

Comment: thank you for your interest, I'll give a look to the iframes use with shinyapps... ^^

Comment: Do that, the downside is that it requires you to run shiny-server instead of just running shiny from inside R. A tip to easily send data to instances of your app is using the GET method.